# Mapreduce Tasktracker blacklisted

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, cloudera

We are using CDH 4.2 with CM 5.0

Recently we stated noticing one of the Tasktracker getting blacklisted, then I had to restart it to bring it back into pool. All machines has same configuration & capacity. But tasktracker  on one specific machine gets blacklisted repetitively.

To find out the root cause I dig into logs and found

9:32:28.117 AM ERROR org.mortbay.log /mapOutput java.lang.IllegalStateException: Committed at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.resetBuffer(Response.java:1023) at org.mortbay.jetty.Response.sendError(Response.java:240) at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$MapOutputServlet.doGet(TaskTracker.java:4283) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1221) at org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer$QuotingInputFilter.doFilter(HttpServer.java:1068) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212) at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212) at org.apache.hadoop.http.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:45) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1212) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:399) at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:766) at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230) at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:928) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212) at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404) at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410) at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

Complete log : http://pastebin.com/BrM47DZu

any kind of help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It because of using hadoop command to format namenode, it deprecated by hadoop2.2.0.
so stop all hadoop process, then format namenode by hdfs command:
bin/hdfs namenode -format